# Set of three self-consistent coupled 'gap' equations

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, list-manipulation, physics

**For a function of the kind of 5 variables, where this function must satisfy the following self-consistent coupled 'gap' equations.**

I want to reproduce the graphics in the paper "Phases of QCD: lattice thermodynamics
and a field theoretical model" by Claudia Ratti, Michael A. Thaler and Wolfram Weise.

[image]

For the coding in Mathematica, I've replaced $\Phi$ by "Phi" and $\Phi^{*}$ by "phi".

```
Nc = 3;
Nf = 2;

\[CapitalLambda] = 587.9;    (*MeV*)
m = 5.6;         (*MeV*)
Tc = 215;
G = 2.44/\[CapitalLambda]^2;
a0 = 3.51;
a1 = -2.47;
a2 = 15.22;
b4 = -1.75;
T0 = 270;



                        
Ep[p_, M_] := Sqrt[p^2 + M^2];


B2[T_] := a0 + a1 (T0/T) + a2 (T0/T)^2;
B4[T_] := b4 (T0/T)^3;

U[\[Phi]_, \[CapitalPhi]_, T_] = (-(1/2)*B2[T]*\[Phi]*\[CapitalPhi] +  B4[T]*Log[1 - 6*\[Phi]*\[CapitalPhi] + 4*(\[CapitalPhi]^3 + \[Phi]^3) - 3*(\[Phi]*\[CapitalPhi])^2])*T^4;


\[CapitalOmega][\[Mu]_, T_, M_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Phi]_] := \[CapitalOmega]0[M] + U[\[Phi], \[CapitalPhi], T] - 2*Nf*NIntegrate[p^2/(2 \[Pi]^2)T (Log[1 + E^(-((3 Ep[p, M])/T) - 3 \[Mu]/T) + 3 E^(-((2 Ep[p, M])/T) - 2 \[Mu]/T) \[CapitalPhi] + 3 E^(-(Ep[p, M]/T) - \[Mu]/T) \[Phi]] + Log[1 + E^(-((3 Ep[p, M])/T) + 3 \[Mu]/T) + 3 E^(-(Ep[p, M]/T) + \[Mu]/T) \[CapitalPhi] + 3 E^(-((2 Ep[p, M])/T) + 2 \[Mu]/T) \[Phi]]), {p, 0, Infinity}];
```

and the gap equations are written as:

```
\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]M[\[Mu]_, T_, M_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Phi]_] := (M - m)/G - 2*Nf*Nc*(4 \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi])^3*M (1/2 \[CapitalLambda] Sqrt[M^2 + \[CapitalLambda]^2] - 1/2 M^2 ArcTanh[\[CapitalLambda]/Sqrt[M^2 + \[CapitalLambda]^2]]) - 2*Nf*NIntegrate[-((3 p^2 (1 + E^((2 (\[Mu] + Ep[p, M]))/T) \[Phi] + 2 E^((\[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) \[CapitalPhi])\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ep\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[p, M])/(2 \[Pi]^2 (1 + E^((3 (\[Mu] + Ep[p, M]))/T) + 3 E^((2 (\[Mu] + Ep[p, M]))/T) \[Phi] + 3 E^((\[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) \[CapitalPhi]))) - (3 E^(\[Mu]/T) p^2 (E^((2 \[Mu])/T) + 2 E^((\[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) \[Phi] +  E^((2 Ep[p, M])/T) \[CapitalPhi])\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ep\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[p, M])/( 2 \[Pi]^2 (E^((3 \[Mu])/T) + E^((3 Ep[p, M])/T) +  3 E^((2 \[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) \[Phi] +  3 E^((\[Mu] + 2 Ep[p, M])/T) \[CapitalPhi])), {p, 0, Infinity}];


\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]\[CapitalPhi][\[Mu]_, T_, M_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Phi]_] :=  T^4 (-(1/2) \[Phi] B2[T] - (6 (\[Phi] + \[Phi]^2 \[CapitalPhi] - 2 \[CapitalPhi]^2) B4[T])/(1 + 4 \[Phi]^3 - 6 \[Phi] \[CapitalPhi] -  3 \[Phi]^2 \[CapitalPhi]^2 + 4 \[CapitalPhi]^3)) -  2*Nf*NIntegrate[(3 E^((\[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) p^2 T (1/(E^((3 \[Mu] - Ep[p, M])/T) + E^((2 Ep[p, M])/T) + 3 E^((2 \[Mu])/T) \[Phi] +  3 E^((\[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) \[CapitalPhi]) + 1/( 1 + E^((3 (\[Mu] + Ep[p, M]))/T) +  3 E^((2 (\[Mu] + Ep[p, M]))/T) \[Phi] +  3 E^((\[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) \[CapitalPhi])))/( 2 \[Pi]^2), {p, 0, Infinity}];


\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]\[Phi][\[Mu]_, T_,  M_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Phi]_] := T^4 (-(1/2) \[CapitalPhi] B2[T] - (6 (\[CapitalPhi] + \[Phi] (-2 \[Phi] + \[CapitalPhi]^2)) B4[T])/(1 + 4 \[Phi]^3 - 6 \[Phi] \[CapitalPhi] - 3 \[Phi]^2 \[CapitalPhi]^2 + 4 \[CapitalPhi]^3)) - 2*Nf*NIntegrate[(3 E^((2 \[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) p^2 T (E^(Ep[p, M]/T)/( 1 + E^((3 (\[Mu] + Ep[p, M]))/T) +  3 E^((2 (\[Mu] + Ep[p, M]))/T) \[Phi] + 3 E^((\[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) \[CapitalPhi]) + 1/(E^((3 \[Mu])/T) + E^((3 Ep[p, M])/T) +  3 E^((2 \[Mu] + Ep[p, M])/T) \[Phi] + 3 E^((\[Mu] + 2 Ep[p, M])/T) \[CapitalPhi])))/(2 \[Pi]^2), {p, 0, Infinity}];
```

I tried to plot these graphs by using FindRoot of all these 3 gap equations and defining the values of Phi, phi and M, and the result will be a function of mu and T. Later I take a desired value for mu and do a Table varying T. For this, I wrote a solution of the type:

```
sol\[Phi][\[Mu]_, T_] :=  x /. FindRoot[{Re[\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]\[CapitalPhi][\[Mu]\, T, w, y, x]] == 0, Re[\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]\[Phi][\[Mu], T, w, y, x]] == 0, Re[\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]M[\[Mu],T, w, y, x]] == 0}, {{x, 0, 0.8}, {y, 0, 0.8}, {w, 10, 350}}];
```

Where "dfdPhi", "dfdphi" and "dfdM" are the gap equations above, but they are simply derivatives of $f$ with respect to $\Phi$, $\Phi^{*}$ and $M$ respectively. In the FindRoot, for solutions of "Phi" I defined a variable "x" from $0.35$ to $0.75$, for "phi" I defined a variable "y" from $0.35$ to $0.75$ as well, and for "M" I defined a variable "w" from $0$ to $350$, which are approximately the range of values the figure.

I tried, as said before, to use Table for plotting Phi vs T, for a specific mu, e.g., mu=340 (the problematic curve), as follows:

```
Table[{T, sol\[CapitalPhi][340, T]}, {T, 1.1, 302, 50}]
```

The result is for a few points is:

```
Out=  {{1.1, -2.91187*10^-37}, {51.1, 0.0217319}, {101.1, 
  0.0569066}, {151.1, 0.159099}, {201.1, 0.421985}, {251.1, 
  0.62148}, {301.1, 0.7305}}
```

The plotted points looks like this:

[image]

And for more points::

```
Table[{T, solPhi[340, T]}, {T, 1, 301, 10}]
```

The result:

```
Out=  {{1.1, -2.91187*10^-37}, {11.1, 0.00453317}, {21.1, 
  0.00861518}, {31.1, 0.0127729}, {41.1, 0.0171036}, {51.1, 
  0.0217319}, {61.1, 0.026818}, {71.1, 0.0325687}, {81.1, 
  0.0392518}, {91.1, 0.0472141}, {101.1, 0.0569066}, {111.1, 
  0.0689161}, {121.1, 0.0840072}, {131.1, 0.103173}, {141.1, 
  0.127685}, {151.1, 0.159099}, {161.1, 0.19903}, {171.1, 
  0.248304}, {181.1, 0.305262}, {191.1, 0.364994}, {201.1, 
  0.421985}, {211.1, 0.473195}, {221.1, 0.694858}, {231.1, 
  0.557162}, {241.1, -0.0897173}, {251.1, 0.62148}, {261.1, 
  0.648192}, {271.1, 0.704975}, {281.1, -0.3734}, {291.1, 
  0.712885}, {301.1, 0.7305}}
```

with plotting:

[image]

As you can see, nothing like the original figure for $\mu=340$ from the paper. It looks like more for $\mu=200$.

Am I doing something wrong or any suggestions? Anything will be welcome!! Thanks.

Comment: Short, focused questions that present a minimal working example get more attention and replies in general. Your question is physics-specific so you will probably have to wait a bit longer for an interested and knowledgeable respondent to take it up.

Comment: Your code does not evaluate successfully with v13.0.1 (`NIntegrate::izero` and `FindRoot::nlnum` errors which then produce `ReplaceAll::reps` errors)

Comment: Parameter `T0` is not defined. Also in your code there is defined function `dfPhi` while in `FindRoot` it used with name `dfdPhi`. Function  `dfdM` diverges, probably it defined with typo.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I gonna check it and edit the question...I simplified and changed the notation to make it shorter here.

Comment: @BobHanlon yes, probably. My version is 12.0, I noticed also it doesn't work in version 11.

Comment: @EverlinMartins It looks like `dfdM` not equals `D[f, M]`. Could you upload function `f` as it is without simplifications?

Comment: @AlexTrounev ok, uploaded my original version...see if you can put it on your Mathematica. What I did was to derivate each term inside of NIntegrate.

Comment: @EverlinMartins Your expression for `f` is  differ from equations  (5),(6), (18), (19)  in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0506234.pdf . Why do you try to reproduce Figure 6 from this paper?

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes, I used a different paper by the same authors for coding this. It is this one https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0609218.pdf I'm trying to reproduce it because for my PhD I gonna work with this model. So I'm trying to reproduce it to get used to programming on Mathematica. The plots are done only in the first paper I referred on the question, but they should be equal. These papers are an attempt to reproduce the data from the Lattice solutions to QCD.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I edited with your recommendations, indeed I found some errors in the coding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code we can reproduce picture for mass and $\Phi$.

```
Nc = 3;
Nf = 2;

Lambda = \[CapitalLambda] = 651;(*MeV*)m = 5.6;(*MeV*)Tc = 215;
G = 10.08 10^-6;
a0 = 3.51;
a1 = -2.47;
a2 = 15.22;
b4 = -1.75;
T0 = 270;




Ep[p_, M_] := Sqrt[p^2 + M^2];
\[CapitalOmega]0[M_] := (M - m)^2/(2 G);

B2[T_] := a0 + a1 (T0/T) + a2 (T0/T)^2;
B4[T_] := b4 (T0/T)^3;

U[\[Phi]_, \[CapitalPhi]_, 
   T_] = (-(1/2)*B2[T]*\[Phi]*\[CapitalPhi] + 
     B4[T]*Log[
       1 - 6*\[Phi]*\[CapitalPhi] + 4*(\[CapitalPhi]^3 + \[Phi]^3) - 
        3*(\[Phi]*\[CapitalPhi])^2])*T^4;


\[CapitalOmega][\[Mu]_, T_, 
   M_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Phi]_] := \[CapitalOmega]0[M] + 
   U[\[Phi], \[CapitalPhi], T] - 
   2*Nf/(2 \[Pi]^2) T *
    NIntegrate[
     p^2 (Log[
         1 + E^(-3 ( Ep[p, M] - \[Mu])/T) + 
          3 E^(-(Ep[p, M] - \[Mu])/T) \[CapitalPhi] + 
          3 E^(-2 (Ep[p, M] - \[Mu])/T) \[Phi]] + 
        Log[1 + E^(-3 ( Ep[p, M] + \[Mu])/T) + 
          3 \[Phi] E^(-(Ep[p, M] + \[Mu])/T) + 
          3 E^(-2 (Ep[p, M] + \[Mu])/T) \[CapitalPhi] ]), {p, 0, 
      Infinity}];



\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]M[\[Mu]_, T_, 
   M_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Phi]_] := (M - m)/G -  
   6*Nf*(4 \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi])^3*(1/4 Lambda M Sqrt[Lambda^2 + M^2] + (
      Lambda M (2 Lambda^2 + M^2))/(8 Sqrt[Lambda^2 + M^2]) + (
      Lambda M^5)/(
      8 (Lambda^2 + M^2)^(3/2) (1 - Lambda^2/(Lambda^2 + M^2))) - 
      1/2 M^3 ArcTanh[Lambda/Sqrt[Lambda^2 + M^2]]) - 
   2*Nf/(2 \[Pi]^2) T*
    NIntegrate[((-((3 E^(-((3 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)) M)/(
          Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] T)) - (
         6 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)) M \[Phi])/(
         Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] T) - (
         3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu])/T) M \[CapitalPhi])/(
         Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] T))/(
        1 + E^(-((3 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)) + 
         3 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)) \[Phi] + 
         3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu])/T) \[CapitalPhi]) + (-((
          3 E^(-((3 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/T)) M)/(
          Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] T)) - (
         3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu])/T) M \[Phi])/(
         Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] T) - (
         6 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/T)) M \[CapitalPhi])/(
         Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] T))/(
        1 + E^(-((3 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/T)) + 
         3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu])/T) \[Phi] + 
         3 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/
           T)) \[CapitalPhi])) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 2];


\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]\[CapitalPhi][\[Mu]_, T_, 
   M_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Phi]_] :=  
  T^4 (-(1/2) \[Phi] B2[
        T] + ((-6 \[Phi] - 6 \[Phi]^2 \[CapitalPhi] + 
         12 \[CapitalPhi]^2) B4[T])/(
      1 - 6 \[Phi] \[CapitalPhi] - 3 \[Phi]^2 \[CapitalPhi]^2 + 
       4 (\[Phi]^3 + \[CapitalPhi]^3))) -  
   2*Nf/(2 \[Pi]^2) T*
    NIntegrate[((3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu])/T))/(
        1 + E^(-((3 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)) + 
         3 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)) \[Phi] + 
         3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu])/T) \[CapitalPhi]) + (
        3 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/T)))/(
        1 + E^(-((3 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/T)) + 
         3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu])/T) \[Phi] + 
         3 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/
           T)) \[CapitalPhi])) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 2];


\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]\[Phi][\[Mu]_, T_,  
   M_, \[CapitalPhi]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  T^4 (-(1/2) \[CapitalPhi] B2[
        T] + ((12 \[Phi]^2 - 6 \[CapitalPhi] - 
         6 \[Phi] \[CapitalPhi]^2) B4[T])/(
      1 - 6 \[Phi] \[CapitalPhi] - 3 \[Phi]^2 \[CapitalPhi]^2 + 
       4 (\[Phi]^3 + \[CapitalPhi]^3)))  - 
   2*Nf/(2 \[Pi]^2) T*
    NIntegrate[((3 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)))/(
        1 + E^(-((3 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)) + 
         3 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu]))/T)) \[Phi] + 
         3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu])/T) \[CapitalPhi]) + (
        3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu])/T))/(
        1 + E^(-((3 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/T)) + 
         3 E^((-Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] - \[Mu])/T) \[Phi] + 
         3 E^(-((2 (Sqrt[M^2 + p^2] + \[Mu]))/
           T)) \[CapitalPhi])) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 2];
```

To compute `M` and $\Phi$ we organize `Module` as follows

```
s[mu_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, x0_, y0_, w0_] := 
 Module[{sol, rut, x, y, w}, 
  sol = FindRoot[{\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]M[mu, T, w, x, y] == 
       0, \[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]\[CapitalPhi][mu, T, w, x, 
        y] == 0, \[Delta]\[CapitalOmega]\[Delta]\[Phi][mu, T, w, x, 
        y] == 0}, {{x, x0}, {y, y0}, {w, w0}}, 
     MaxIterations -> 1000] // Quiet; root = {x, y, w} /. sol; root]
```

We use `Do` lope to compute `m` and $\Phi$ in the range $\mu$ and `T`

```
Do[sols[mu][0] = s[mu, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 300];
 Do[sols[mu][i] = 
    s[mu, 1 + i 5, sols[mu][i - 1][[1]], sols[mu][i - 1][[2]], 
     sols[mu][i - 1][[3]]];, {i, 1, 62}];, {mu, {0, 200, 270, 340}}]
```

Visualization

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Table[{1 + i 5, sols[mu][i][[3]]}, {i, 0, 62}], {mu, {0, 200, 270, 
    340}}], PlotLegends -> 
  Table[Row[{"\[Mu] = ", mu}], {mu, {0, 200, 270, 340}}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"T", "m"}]

ListPlot[Table[
  Table[{1 + i 5, sols[mu][i][[1]]}, {i, 0, 62}], {mu, {0, 200, 270, 
    340}}], PlotLegends -> 
  Table[Row[{"\[Mu] = ", mu}], {mu, {0, 200, 270, 340}}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"T", "\[CapitalPhi]"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Yes, it worked! They are very similar to the original ones!! You solved my problem. Now I need to study your code. I hope this can help many others too. I can't thank you enough. Anyhow, many thanks, Alex!! God bless you!

Comment: @EverlinMartins You are welcome!